# Error: Processing is failing in Autodesk-Forge when converting the image to 3D

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I am using https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/recap-walkthrough-photo.to.3d for converting image to 3D, but at the end of the execution its throwing an error when the image is getting processed.

Any Help on this would be highly appreciated.

data: {
Usage: '0.44537496566772',
Resource: '/photoscene/jsjshdfjsdhgjfsdjf/progress',
Photoscene: {
photosceneid: 'jsjshdfjsdhgjfsdjf',
progressmsg: 'ERROR',
progress: '100'
}
}

is the error. Reason for this error is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact the support via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, providing as much information as possible, e.g.:

- how many images you uploaded, and what was their resolution?
- how did you upload these files? If you used a custom code or script, could you share it?
- when did you run these requests, and what was the Forge Client ID you used for them?

EDIT:

While the response isn't very descriptive, the engineering team confirms that this error is typically caused by insufficient input data. In this particular case only 4 images were uploaded, and the algorithm wasn't able to reconstruct the 3D screen from those.