# Unable to get the output file in Reality Capture API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-realitycapture

I am trying to get the proper output from the API but each time it throws an error, and not having enough information about the error makes it more default here is the below example and same happened with other files too

```json
{
    "Usage": "0.47476506233215",
    "Resource": "/photoscene/XkQN53pc1WCI66ExM6DnjVmKCYb6ZyRZ8ntmwdTjj8U/progress",
    "Photoscene":
    {
        "photosceneid": "XkQN53pc1WCI66ExM6DnjVmKCYb6ZyRZ8ntmwdTjj8U",
        "progressmsg": "ERROR",
        "progress": "100"
    }
}
```

What are the guidelines for the input images?
Do we have any sample input images for POC?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I recommend to have a look at the https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api blog post.

Comment: @denis-grigor this time i followed the same instructions but results are same

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, these errors are often caused by insufficient input data. For example, check out this Stack Overflow question: [Error: Processing is failing in Autodesk-Forge when converting the image to 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476068/error-processing-is-failing-in-autodesk-forge-when-converting-the-image-to-3d/72529069#72529069).

Consider providing more information about your particular case - how many images have you used to reconstruct the scene, what resolution/quality were they?